# the volume in hydraulic retention time is of reactor/container or liquid

Tags: chemical-engineering

I have a tiny reactor, and the volume I need is 425ml. If there is no/few other reactants, then the volume in `hydraulic retention time` is clear: reactor/container's volume. and hrt is `V/u`(V is 425ml, u is flow rate) But if I fill 80% of container with something like lime mud, the real volume of water is only 20% left -- 85ml. How is my `V` should be? 425 or 85ml? IOW, the volume in hydraulic retention time is of reactor/container or liquid?

Comment: The usable volume.. ie that not filled by mud.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are trying to do might be a bit bespoke, can you elaborate on what you need the HRT to be a measure of ? I.e. What are you trying to achieve with the measure? This link provides a general definition from which I would have suggested that it is the liquid volume you are interested in. https://www.ssiaeration.com/how-to-optimize-hydraulic-retention-time/#calculations

Answer (score 0):

Water volume is 85 ml now, so the hrt is 85 ml/u. The liquid retention time because the mud doesn't react, right?

Comment: _because the mud doesn't react_ IMO, it's not right, because the mud will release Ca2+

Comment: Then you should consider the mud to calculate the hrt.